# how to make php submit button follow URL with Parameters vs Echo (current setup)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

My Code:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
$drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
$drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3'];
    echo "<Table style='background:#ccc; width:800px; font-family:Open Sans;height:60px;'>   <tr><Td width='500px'>

You selected $drop $drop_2 $drop_3</td><td>
<a target='_parent' href='http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=&description=&short_description=&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&make=$drop&v_model=$drop_2&&engine=$drop_3&&category=3'>See XXX For Your XXX</a></tr></table>";
//echo $drop_3." ".$drop." ".$drop_2;

} ?>
```

What I aim to do instead of displaying a table with the variables, is to have it follow the link

```
www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=&description=&short_description=&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&make=$drop&v_model=$drop_2&&engine=$drop_3&&category=3
```

upon clicking the submit button.

I tried

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 1 )
header("Location: http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com");
```

However, it doesn't not work, the page just reloads.

please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this two ways, either change your code so that you have:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$drop = $_POST['drop_1'];
$drop_2 = $_POST['drop_2'];
$drop_3 = $_POST['drop_3'];

header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?make=$drop&v_model=$drop_2&engine=$drop_3');

} 
?>
```

However the best bet would be to change your form so that the action is the URL you're wanting to post to e.g. http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/ and change the method to "GET" and then name your form fields appropriately (make, v_model, and engine).

Comment: Doing the above mentioned modification just refreshed the page, it does not redirect. I've already tried that before, any other suggestions?